# updating and quering rating in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb collection `users`. 
Each user have field called `rating` which is between 1 and 5. It means that when user votes on another user he 'gives' him his vote which is a number between 1 and 5. I have a problem with storing this data in mongo document beacause I have to query user collection by `rating` field and I have to update it atomicly...

1. If I store both rating and number of votes when I can update `votes_number` with `$inc` operator but I cant atomicly set `rating = ((rating*votes) + vote_val)/(votes+1)`
2. I could just keep sum of votes and votes number in document and update both using `$inc` but then I cant query like `WHERE votes_sum/votes_num > 3`...

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use option two from above and then combine it with a cached result field.  You can set up the data flow so the result field remains consistent with the rest of the document by using the filter predicate on your update.

Step one is to add a new field to your schema which will be your cached rating field.  This will allow you to perform your range query without having to do the dynamic division.  The problem you'll run into there is that you can't atomically increment the votes_sum & votes_num fields AND in the same atomic operation set the cached rating fields.  So here's what you do.

1)  Atomically increment the votes_sum and votes_num fields
2)  Grab the _id, votes_sum & votes_num for the updated document
3)  Update the rating but, as part of the filter predicate, include the _id, expected votes_sum and expected votes_num fields.

```
db.collection.update({_id: $id, votes_sum: $votes_sum, votes_num: $votes_num}, {$set: {rating: $votes_sum / $votes_num}});
```

This will ensure that nothing has changed since you updated the doc.  If someone else comes along and updates those fields in between you updating them and generating the rating then the doc will not be returned in the find part of the update statement and thus it will not be updated with stale data

This pattern takes advantage of the fact that writes are atomic at the document level in MongoDB so you don't have to worry about the consistency of data within a document.  The nice thing is that the rating will be set correctly because every operation to update the votes_sum and votes_num fields is followed by an update to rating.

See here for some sample code: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/